# What should I do if compass lies

Tags: iphone, ios, compass-geolocation

What should I do if the compass on two or more different devices give me different headings? I tried to calibrate the compass on devices but anyway sometimes they show me differents headings.

Comment: Are you asking about how to troubleshoot the compass inaccuracy?

Comment: May be exist method to equalize different compass headings on different devices, but I don't know device direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if 2 iOS devices give you 2 different readings then at least one of them has uncalibrated hardware. So is this a hardware question? I don't think there is much to do in terms of the program, especially if you have no idea what the exact skew is.

Comment: I want to solve the problem with software. I put two or more devices on a table, I calibrate them, but they show me different headings. Can I know who lie?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "know who lies" - when you're utilizing hardware, all you can do is trust the reading it gives you. Unless there is more than 1 way to get a reading, which I'm pretty sure there isn't.

Comment: In general I want to put devices in common local coordinate system to know how they rotated relative to each other. Gyroscope can help me, but I dont know first direction because gyroscope always start from 0.

Comment: Maybe it possible without compass. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, none that I can think of - but that's just because I don't have much experience with the Gyro. It sounds doable.

Answer (score 3):

Since the iPhone compass "works just like a magnetic-needle compass":

> The accuracy of digital compass headings can be affected by magnetic or other environmental interference, including interference caused by proximity to the magnets contained in the iPhone earbuds. The compass may need to be calibrated from time to time ([Apple: iPhone and iPad: Calibrating Compass](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2767?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)).

You have several options for fixing the compass:

1. **Follow the directions!** Move the device in a figure eight motion. However, this looks like it isn't working for you.
2. **"[d]isregard the message to calibrate"**. Some areas have more magnetic interference than others, like in a car because of its dashboard. You can just leave it alone because "[t]he device will eventually recalibrate after several turns. Note that it may need to periodically recalibrate while you are driving, depending on the level of magnetic interference present."
3. **Reboot (Not the "Slide to Power Off" reboot).** Hold the power button and home button until the Apple logo appears.

I'm pretty sure those are your options. There may be more, so I'll do more research.

If you just want to see which compass is wrong, get a **real** compass and compare it to the headings on the two iPhones. Which ever one it matches up with, the other phone is wrong. If you don't have a real compass, you can follow [this](http://adventure.howstuffworks.com/outdoor-activities/hiking/compass2.htm) tutorial to make a homemade one (which is more fun)!

Hope this helps!